# When I press space, my character doesn't always jump in my Unity2D project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gB1F9G0JXOo&t=11865s
I'm watching this tutorial and I did everything the same as the guy in the video did until the "Player Jumping" part, when his character can jump whenever he presses the space button, but for me it doesn't work the same way. Can somebody help or tell me what is the problem?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float moveForce = 10f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpForce = 11f;

    private float movementX;

    private Rigidbody2D myBody;

    private SpriteRenderer sr;

    private Animator anim;
    private string WALK_ANIMATION = "Walk";

    private void Awake()
    {
        myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        PlayerMoveKeyboard();
        AnimatePlayer();

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        PlayerJump();
    }

    void PlayerMoveKeyboard()
    {

        movementX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        
        transform.position += new Vector3(movementX, 0f, 0f) * moveForce * Time.deltaTime;

    }

    void AnimatePlayer()
    {

        // we are going to the right side
        if (movementX > 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool(WALK_ANIMATION, true);  
            sr.flipX = false;
        }

        // we are going to the left side
        else if (movementX < 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool(WALK_ANIMATION, true);
            sr.flipX = true;
        }

        else
        {
            anim.SetBool(WALK_ANIMATION, false);
        }

    }

    void PlayerJump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            myBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        }
    }

} // class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your jump function from the FixedUpdate into the normal Update Function.
That should fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I just don't understand why this code works for the guy in the video but doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

`Update` gets called every frame and thus captures every input while `FixedUpdate` gets called in a fixed offset to update the physics logic of the engine. Now when you are looking for keyboard input, you want to always do that in Update, never in `FixedUpdate` because you'll miss input that was given to the player between the fixed update frames.

But since you want to do physics related changes only in FixedUpdate, you want to split the code between the two methods.

```
bool shouldJump = false;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        shouldJump = true;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (shouldJump)
    {
        myBody.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        shouldJump = false;
    }
}
```

---

I have looked into the code in the video and he does the jump-logic in `FixedUpdate`. It seems weird to me and this is definitely bad practice. But one of the comments below addresses your issue as well and proposes a similar solution.